# Getting gwt hibernate example code to work with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, gwt

I am starting out with GWT and hibernate. I'm going through the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.

I downloaded the sample code provided with the tutorial (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt_hibernate_base.zip). This is a simple music store where you can add an account and records. I am able to run this and successfully add accounts and records to the database by doing the following commands:

```
(in the data directory) java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server

ant build hosted
```

Here is the build.xml file used to build this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="Guestbook" default="build" basedir=".">

  <!-- Define gwt.home, gwt.dev.jar, appengine.sdk.home -->
  <property file="build.properties"/>

  <path id="project.class.path">
    <pathelement location="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <pathelement location="${gwt.home}/gwt-user.jar"/>
    <!-- Add any additional non-server libs (such as JUnit) -->
    <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
      <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <target name="libs" description="Copy libs to WEB-INF/lib">
    <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" file="${gwt.home}/gwt-servlet.jar" />
    <!-- Add any additional server libs that need to be copied -->
    <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" flatten="true">
      <fileset dir="lib/">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="javac" depends="libs" description="Compile java source">
    <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8"
        destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes"
        source="1.5" target="1.5" nowarn="true"
        debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
      <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <!-- can add additional arguments like -logLevel INFO or -style PRETTY -->
  <target name="gwtc" depends="javac" description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${gwt.home}/${gwt.dev.jar}"/>
      </classpath>
      <!-- add jvmarg -Xss16M or similar if you see a StackOverflowError -->
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
      <arg value="com.google.musicstore.MusicStore"/>
    </java>
  </target>

  <target name="hosted" depends="javac" description="Run hosted mode">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="src"/>
        <path refid="project.class.path"/>
        <pathelement location="${gwt.home}/${gwt.dev.jar}"/>
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
      <arg value="-startupUrl"/>
      <arg value="MusicStore.html"/>
      <arg value="com.google.musicstore.MusicStore"/>
      <!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->
    </java>
  </target>

  <target name="build" depends="gwtc" description="Build this project" />

  <target name="clean" description="Cleans this project">
    <delete dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" failonerror="false" />
    <delete dir="war/musicstore" failonerror="false" />
  </target>
```

Now I would like to get this simple example working in eclipse. I created a project called MusicStore using the gwt eclipse plugin. I then copied over the tutorial files without changing them. I can't post an image but here is a link to my eclipse project structure:

http://oi50.tinypic.com/t6rn2w.jpg

Again, I start by running

```
(in the data directory) java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server
```

Then I try to run my project in eclipse but hibernate doesn't work. When I try to add an account in the UI it alerts "Failed to save account" and I get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session.

Please let me know how I should go about getting the sample code working with eclipse. I think that many users new to hibernate will also want to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically eclipse cannot find your hibernate libraries. That is because your build.xml is for building a war file. Eclipse doesn't read it so it doesn't have any of your build information in there.

A quick solution to this is to just go to the "Build Path" properties in Eclipse and make sure your /lib directory is included in the "Libraries" tab. Then eclipse will know where you are keeping your libraries.

A better solution would be to use something like Maven. Then the Maven Plugin for Eclipse will automatically look at the Maven build file and configure the Eclipse project so that it can detect where the libraries are held etc...

Comment: Is there any simple way to do this with Maven because I am failing for a few days now to get together a decent setup ..